# Moodle Event Heirarchy

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

What core Moodle events will allow me to see when a student navigates between areas of a course?  I need to build an event trigger plugin, to call an external REST endpoint, every time a student navigates between screens, begins or ends a course module, etc.  The [Event API docs](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Events_API#Event_dispatching_and_observers) has a long list of events, however I cannot find anything which details when the event will actually fire.  Also, the only activity I can find, which seems to *remotely* relate to what I'm looking for is `course_module_viewed` and, unfortunately, that event name repeats in many areas:

```
core\event\course_module_viewed
mod_lti\event\course_module_viewed  
mod_page\event\course_module_viewed 
mod_resource\event\course_module_viewed 
mod_url\event\course_module_viewed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right that you want "course_module_viewed" events - but that event is (*should be*, because it ties into default activity completion options) implemented by each activity/resource type, because it could mean different things.  So if the activity is a "page", then viewing it will trigger `mod_page\event\course_module_viewed` and if the activity is a SCORM package, `mod_scorm\event\course_module_viewed`.  All of these should extend the abstract `core\event\course_module_viewed` class.

There is not a default event for moving between pages within an activity - at that level of granularity you are dependent on whether the implementers of that plugin decided to log events for this or not, or indeed whether the activity even ***has*** pages.

Other events you may be interested in are `core\event\course_viewed` and `core\event\course_completed` which only exist in core, and the various other events that each individual activity you're likely to encounter in your course content fires off. Eg. for a SCORM activity, you might be interested in the "mod_scorm\event\status_submitted" event